# is there a RegExp that can get the string of a list of ID's?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, find

I have a script that search a mail body.

in the mail body a get a list of ID's like below:
Batch: yt166161
Section:567-947
Sys_id: 1234
Sys_id: 6543
Sys_id: 0974

I need to extract only the number after the Sys_id: and put the in an array.

I'm working on JavaScript

Comment: What if the string were `"Sys_id: 1234 My_id: 5678 3175"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `/[0-9]+/gm` to extract the number.

ex:

```
const str = 'Sys_id: 1234 Sys_id: 6543 Sys_id: 0974';
const regex = /[0-9]+/gm;
const matches = str.match(regex);
console.log(matches);
```

output:
`[ "1234" , "6543" , "0974" ]`

Comment: thanks for your rapid response. but i need only the numbers after the "sys_id:" string. in the mail there are more information (with others strings and numbers).